# Limit of inverse functions

Tags: limits, functions, inverse-function

This is a question of mine that arose recently.

> Let's have a real-valued function $f$ with domain $\mathbb{R}$, that is strictly
>   decreasing and bijective on $\mathbb{R}$. Also, we have that $\lim_\limits{x\to -\infty}{f(x)}=+\infty$ and $\lim_\limits{x\to +\infty}{f(x)}=-\infty$. Prove that $\lim_\limits{x\to +\infty}{f^{-1}(x)}=-\infty$.

So, my questions are:

1) How to prove this, **without** infimum and supremum and without using the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of a limit at all?

2) Do we have to have both $\lim_\limits{x\to -\infty}{f(x)}=+\infty$ and  $\lim_\limits{x\to +\infty}{f(x)}=-\infty$ to conclude the result requested to prove, or is only one of those limits required?

3) Can we deduce more things about other limits and special properties of $f^{-1}(x)$, e.g. about $\lim_\limits{x\to -\infty}{f^{-1}(x)}$?

(I think that the above conclusions all seem very interesting from a mathematical aspect!)

Comment: You can only talk about $f^{-1}$ when $f$ is a bijection, with the current conditions, this is not true.

Comment: Do you assume $f$ to be continuous?

Comment: strictly monotonic  functions are invertible?

Comment: @Jason If $f$ is not continuous, then $f^{-1}$ does not exists.

Comment: @Hetebrij: That's not entirely true. Rather, if $f$ is strictly monotonic but not continuous, then $f$ is invertible, but the domain of its inverse is not all of $\Bbb R.$

Comment: @Mathematician42: Injectivity is sufficient, per my comment above.

Comment: @Jason: I wonder how you propose to prove anything without using the relevant definitions.... At any rate, some of the conditions are superfluous. Consider $f(x):=e^{-x}$ for example.

Comment: @CameronBuie To simplify things a bit, I made $f$ a bijection, so that its inverse is a function and not a partial function, as Wikipedia suggests here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function

Comment: @Jason, how do you define a continuous function?

Comment: @ Cameron Buie : Agreed, although, if the domain of the inverse is not all of $\mathbb{R}$, we require some argument to ensure that the expression $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}f^{-1}(x)$ makes sense.

@ Jason : Think about $f^{-1}$, does it also have to be a strictly decreasing function? This might set you on the right track.

Comment: isn't $f$ continuous now? A monotone function has jump discontinuities only. If $f$ has a positive jump, it would not be surjective.

Comment: @Crostul The "exercise" (for my question 1) doesn't state such a thing. If it can be proven, then all right.

Comment: @Hetebrij No, an example of a non-continuous function is the following function: $f(x)=-x$ for $x\leq 0$ and $f(x)=-x-1$, for $x>0$ (that is a piecewise function)

Comment: @Jason, that function is not bijective.

Comment: @Hetebrij Why isn't it?

Comment: @Jason Because $f(x) \neq -1$ for all $x$.

Comment: @Hetebrij OK, see the new "exercise" and tell me whether now the function would have a problem.

Comment: how do you define $\lim_{x\to \infty} f^{-1}(x) = -\infty$ without $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition?

Comment: @user251257 Not austere, as you would define it in high school mathematics. Only by describing the notion of it. But certain inequalities may be used, such that there is a smaller number for every number that is value of f.

Comment: @Jason: like $f^{-1}$ is unbounded from below?

Comment: @Jason: The wikipedia article is a bit misleading in its phrasing. It should say that if $f:X\to Y$ is an injection but not a bijection, then its inverse is a partial function on $Y.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments, I use the following "definition" for $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) = -\infty$:
$$ \forall K \in \mathbb R : \exists x\in\mathbb R : f(x) < K. $$
In general it is not the same, but for decreasing functions it is. $\lim_{x\to -\infty} f(x) = \infty$ is "defined" analogously.

There is nothing fancy here.

1. Notice that $f^{-1}$ is strictly decreasing as for $y_1,y_2\in f(\mathbb R)$ with $y_1 = f(x_1) > f(x_2) = y_2$ we have $x_1 < x_2$, otherwise it would contradict that $f$ is strictly decreasing.
2. Let $K\in\mathbb R$. Then, from $\lim_{x\to -\infty} f(x) = \infty$ there exists some $x\in\mathbb R$ with $f(x) > f(K)$, thus $f^{-1}(y) < f^{-1}(f(K)) = K$ for $y=f(x)$. That is $\lim_{y\to \infty} f^{-1}(y) = -\infty$.

   On the other hand from $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) = -\infty$ there exists some $\tilde x\in\mathbb R$ with $f(\tilde x) < f(K)$, thus $f^{-1}(\tilde y) > f^{-1}(f(K)) = K$ for $\tilde y = f(\tilde x)$. That is, $\lim_{y\to-\infty} f^{-1}(y) = \infty$.

Comment: May you, if you have the kindness, provide a similar proof using the $\epsilon-\delta$ austere limit definition? Just underneath the current proof. Also, thank you very much!!

Comment: @Jason: It is basically the same. The $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition for $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = -\infty$ would be $\forall K\in\mathbb R : \exists x_0\in \mathbb R : \forall x > x_0 : f(x) < K$.