Limit of function whose inverse has limit approaching infinity at finite point
Consider a continuous strictly monotone function $f:(-1,1)\to\mathbb{R}$, where
$$\lim_{x\to1}f(x)=\infty, \lim_{x\to-1}f(x)=-\infty$$
I have proved that this function is bijective. I want to prove that the inverse function $f^{-1}:\mathbb{R}\to(-1,1)$ is such that
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f^{-1}(x)=1$$
using the definition of limits at infinity. Since $f(x)$ approaches infinity as $x$ approaches $1$, I know that I have that
$$\forall N>0 \; \exists \delta>0 : \forall x\in(-1,1) \left[|x-1|<\delta \implies f(x)>N\right].$$
I can see that this is very similar to the definition of a limit at infinity. I know that $f^{-1}(x)$ should $1$ as $x$ approaches infinity, and it seems trivial from simply looking at how function inverses are defined and such, but can I manipulate the above expression to achieve the formal definition of a limit at infinity?

How did you prove that $f$ is bijective?

@AnneBauval perhaps the OP meant strictly monotone?

Similar/related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1719099/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3121438/42969

@SohamSaha Strict monotonicity is oviously assumed, but I am asking the OP about their I have proved that this function is bijective. [...] the inverse function $f^{-1}:\Bbb R→(−1,1)$

Since you already know that $f$ is bijective, little remains to write.
Given $\epsilon>0$, assume wlog $\epsilon<2$ (so that $1-\epsilon\in(-1,1)$), and let $A:=f(1-\epsilon)$. Then, since $f^{-1}$ is strictly increasing:
$$\forall y>A\quad f^{-1}(y)>1-\epsilon,$$
q.e.d.
